# How do I use opencv to fit a line into a curve like this

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am wondering how can I achieve this?

[image: tangent line]

This is is the line I want to fit to the image.

I have tried Houghline transform. But I am unable to achieve this result, and I got something like this:

[image: tangent line attempt]

properties of the line:
The line has to be tangent to the black region, not cutting through it.

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?

Comment: houghline transform using openvc

Comment: Can you describe properties of the line. You can have different lines that are tangent to the dark region.

Comment: added the description

Comment: where is the description?

Comment: The line has to be tangent to the black region, not cutting through the black region.

Comment: I will try both methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is already thresholded, therefore you can easily [findContours()](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours)
This will give you a detailed list of points for the largest contours (you can choose to retrieve the largest as a flag).

If you want to simplify it, you can using [approxPolyDP](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#approxpolydp). 
Play with the epsilon parameter to get a simpler path.

I'm not sure how a single line can be a tangent to the majority of this complex outline.

Answer (score 2):

You can find contours, apply convex hull algorithm, then select edge you need.